# New user unable to login oracle instead showing oracle

Tags: oracle

I have created new user but i am unable to login.

```
create user c##nisar identified by nisar
```

when i am trying to login with following command it is showing oracle help .

```
sqlplus / as c##nisar
```

Comment: sqlplus c##nisar/nisar@<sid or service name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grant him right to `connect`, and I guess you also want to create some stuff by this user, so add also `resourse`.

Run by `SYS`:

```
grant connect, resourse to c##nisar;
```